# Does Firebase load all the items when you use a limitToFirst or limitToLast?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

For example, I have a database structure like this:

```
"chatMessages": {
    "chat1": {
      "m1": {
        "name": "eclarke",
        "message": "The relay seems to be malfunctioning.",
        "timestamp": 1459361875337
      },
      "m2": { ... },
      "m3": { ... }
    },
    "chat2": { ... },
    "chat3": { ... }
  }
```

Now, some chats have, let's say, 1,000 messages. When I use a `LimitToLast` to retrieve the last 100 messages. Does Firebase first load all the 1,000 messages before sending me the 100 messages I want to retrieve or does it limit the loading to the 100 messages I really need? I am not certain, because I read a lot about keeping the database as flat as possible.

In case Firebase does load all 1,000 messages first, should I consider nesting it in a specific way?

I hope the community can make things clear to me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two possibilities here:

1. There is an index (either implicit on key, or explicitly [defined by you](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data#defining_data_indexes)) for the query, the data is filtered on the server.
2. There is no index for the query, in which case all data at the location is retrieved and ordered/filtered on the client.

Comment: Thank you Frank. I try to understand what happens, but in order to limit the server load it's best to give it an order by child (timestamp) then?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can limit by key or by value too. But your question was rather abstract on that front, so couldn't be more specific in my answer.

Comment: I agree, it is an abstract formulation. I really try to understand what happens on the server side, as I don't want to unnecessarily overload the servers. Really appreciate your answer and it gives me a better insight. Thanks again!